# How to store key and value elements from object in a array inside foreach loop nodejs

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am creating a dialog flow chatbot to display the list of hotels available from the database to the user.

Example:

```
User: Hi. want to book a hotel.    
Bot: Please find the list of hotels below.    

0)
hotelname: GrandHyatt
city: Mumbai
price: 100
1)
hotelname: Leelaplace
city: Banglore
price: 110
2)
hotelname: OberaiHotel
city: Mumbai
price: 150
3)
hotelname: Taj Hotel
city: Mumbai
price: 180
```

I want to display it in this format.

The code below contains the results that I extract from the database. Also, I tried to modify the format to display to the user.

```
var result=[  //This is the result I get from the database
    {
        Price: 100,
        Availability: 'Yes',
        City: 'Mumbai',
        HotelName: 'GrandHyatt'
      },
      {
        HotelName: 'Leelaplace',
        Price: 110,
        City: 'Banglore',
        Availability: 'Yes'
      },
      {
        HotelName: 'OberaiHotel',
        City: 'Mumbai',
        Availability: 'Yes',
        Price: 150
      },
      {
        HotelName: 'Taj Hotel',
        Availability: 'yes',
        Price: 180,
        City: 'Mumbai'
      }
];

 
var values = [];
var prices =[];
for(let i =0;i<result.length;i++) {                               
    var hotelname=result[i].HotelName;
    var city=result[i].City;
    var price=result[i].Price;               
                
    values.push({
        hotelname: hotelname,
        city: city,
        price: price,     
    })
}

let arr=[]
values.forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log(index +")");
    for (const key in element) {
        console.log(`${key}: ${element[key]}`); //The results gets displayed as expected 
    }
})
```

Results that get printed:

```
0)
hotelname: GrandHyatt
city: Mumbai
price: 100
1)
hotelname: Leelaplace
city: Banglore
price: 110
2)
hotelname: OberaiHotel
city: Mumbai
price: 150
3)
hotelname: Taj Hotel
city: Mumbai
price: 180
```

I  get the result printed in the above format as expected. Now, I want to store the  "`${key}: ${element[key]}`" in a variable so that I can  pass the variable name  to the user like shown below:

```
df.setResponseText("Please find the details below:"+'${key}: ${element[key]}');//This does not work...how can I store and pass as a variable to this.
```

I tried creating a function and using `forEach` loop inside the function and am returning the `"${key}: ${element[key]}"`.This also did not work.

I am a beginner at `Nodejs` and figuring out all possibilities. Could you please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand your question, but I guess you need to store the option object in a variable not only a key. I don't know if the below code would help.

```
var result = [
//This is the result I get from the database
{
  Price: 100,
  Availability: "Yes",
  City: "Mumbai",
  HotelName: "GrandHyatt",
},
{
  HotelName: "Leelaplace",
  Price: 110,
  City: "Banglore",
  Availability: "Yes",
},
{
  HotelName: "OberaiHotel",
  City: "Mumbai",
  Availability: "Yes",
  Price: 150,
},
{
  HotelName: "Taj Hotel",
  Availability: "yes",
  Price: 180,
  City: "Mumbai",
},
];

let values = result.map((hotelDetails) => {
  return {
    hotelname: hotelDetails.HotelName,
    city: hotelDetails.City,
    price: hotelDetails.Price,
  };
});

let data = {};
values.forEach((element, index, array) => {
  console.log(index + ")");
  for (const key in element) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${element[key]}`); 
  }
  data[index] = element;
});
console.log(data);
```

the data object contains your options indexed to be printed

Answer (score 0):

OT: Man, invest in a code formatter because it's really hard to read ...

1. Why are you breaking building the `values` array and sending it? You can:

```
for(let i =0;i<result.length;i++) {
  //...
  console.log(i+')')
  console.log("hotelname: "+ hotelname)
  console.log("city" + result[i].City)
}
```

2. Why do you put a value into a variable to add to an array later? Use

```
values.push  ({
   //...
   city: result[i].City,              
})
```

Also if you transform variables into objects, and the object key has an identical name as the variable, you can use the short syntax: `values.push  ({hotelname, city, price})`

3. Why are you processing the result from the database when you can get it ready right away? (Read about `SELECT ColumnName AS alias`)
4. Why are you using `var`? Start using `let`, 'const' instead. There are quite a lot of context problems with `var`.
5. Why aren't you using a unique hotel code from the database? Let 1 hotel disappear/show up for you. And you already have the data mixed up...
6. Do you see the difference between the apostrophes used?

```js
       console.log(`xx ${key}: ${element[key]}`)
df.setResponseText('xx ${key}: ${element[key]}');
```

Even the syntax coloring looks different ...